# how to stop Visual studio to parse the minified file generated by asp.net in Visual studio 10?

Tags: visual-studio, crash

i am using the visual studio for asp.net and it's create a problem that my code generate minified file through squishit. so after some days it have more then dozen files minfied (css and javascript  both).

so if i take a search on entire sollution it's take a long time or crash visual studio.

how can i disallow parsing this  minified file (css and javascript) in visual studio ?

OR.

can i delete them automatically when they genereate a new minified files.

OR

visual studio can exclude them automatically (when they have prefix or suffix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 'post build step' - so you and VS works with normal (human-readable) asp file, but for deployment you can override this file with minified one.